# TypeError: undefined is not a function on mobile (but no error on desktop)

Tags: jquery, mobile

This line: `var welcome_message = $('.alert-info').text().includes("signed up")` is causing the error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$(".alert-info").text().includes("signed up")')

I'm having trouble identifying what the issue is since it works perfectly when I'm running it on desktop.

Comment: What is `includes()` method? Looks like your issue comes from here

Comment: Oh... I thought it was a standard JS method to find a substring. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: Ok I'll switch it to indexOf. Thanks for pointing that out. I was just confused as to why it wasn't working only on mobile.

Comment: `This is a new technology, part of the ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) standard.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Browser_compatibility